# Kendo Upload cannot get Byte array of selected file

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, upload, client

How can take the byte array data of selected file? from `select` event i can get `e.files[0].rawFile` but i cannot find where is stored the byte[]. i want this data on client side

Answer (score 1):

I found the documentation pretty poor on this matter as well. The documentation is geared at using a REST endpoint to do server side processing of the file. Most of the examples of client side processing are just for showing the file names, which isn't super useful if you want to do any meaningful client-side validation of the content of the file. In my case, I have CSV files I want to do some pre-processing on the client side. The trick is you need to use the HTML5 a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Here is an example in AngularJS where $ctrl.fileContent will have the content of a CSV file.

```js
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            var $ctrl = this;

            // function called by kendo upload component
            $ctrl.onSelect = function(e) {
                var message = e.files.map(function(file) {
                    return $ctrl.readFile(file);
                }).join(', ');

                // log file names being uploaded
                console.log('event :: files select (' + message + ')');
            };

            // read file and do basic validation
            $ctrl.readFile = function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var text = reader.result;
                    console.log('File contents :: ' + text);
                    $ctrl.fileContent = text;
                };

                reader.readAsText(file.rawFile);

                // return file name
                return file.name;
            };

            // function called by kendo upload component
            $ctrl.onUpload = function(e) {
                // todo
                console.log('Uploading file');
                console.log($ctrl.fileContent);
            };
        }]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="content-panel">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h4>Upload CSV files</h4>
            <input name="files"
                type="file"
                kendo-upload
                k-async="{ saveUrl: '$ctrl.save', removeUrl: 'remove', autoUpload: false }"
                k-select="$ctrl.onSelect"
                k-validation="{ allowedExtensions: ['csv']}"
                k-upload="$ctrl.onUpload"
                />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
function(data) {
    data = btoa(data);
    var bytesArr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       bytesArr.push(data.charCodeAt(i)); 
    }
    return new Uint8Array(bytesArr);
}
```

Comment: what is 'atob'??

Comment: @GomuGomuNoRocket [w3schools atob](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_win_atob.asp)

Comment: but i realized in your case it maybe should be btoa